# kendo grid dataitem , how do i get items that are objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I am trying to populate a  Kendo list box from a kendo grid selection. The way it should work is that when a user selects the row a column in the grid  will display that item in the list box. The problem I am having is that I cannot access the object in the dataitem I want to use. the object  is visible and the fields inside it are correct I just need to be able to send that object to a list box where it looks for the valuefield and textfield.

I have been searching for a solution for a few days now. I am wondering really what I should be searching for at this point. I cant figure out what it is that will allow me to pull this object out of the dataItem to use  it in my list box.The dataItem is [object(anonymous function)],The object inside the dataItem is:RolesLists [object(init)]. It is the RolesLists that I need to retrieve and send to the List Box. Nothing works as dataItem.RolesLists stays undefined.

I get the  grid data in the grid , and I get the list box  to send the data to in the second line. I then get the dataItem from the grid which gives me everything selected. I remove anything currently in the list box.Finally I add the dataItem, which should be dataitem.RolesLists. That comes up as undefined.

```
    var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
    var listboxSelected = $('#selected').data('kendoListBox');
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(grid.select());
    listboxSelected.remove(listboxSelected.items());
    listboxSelected.add(dataItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out I was making an error , my  apologies for wasting everyones time. The code above was correct and you can use it if you wish to retrieve an item from a Kendo grid and populate any element with it.